# Why isn't media respecting my allowed file type settings

Tags: 7, entities, media

In my field settings for a media based image field, I have this:

[image]

When I upload an image and click next I get the following:

[image]

both of those types allow image files, but this particular field should only allow items to be classified as images.  Why is the setting not being respected?

Answer (score 1):

My guess based on my own experience is that the uploaded file shares the same mime type as the publication files configuration, and the system is asking the user which file type to designate. Example, if both types allow for PNGs, it won't be able to determine the file type for you. Try uploading a file who's mimetype isn't shared by others; you won't get that dialog.

Comment: Then what in the work is that Allowed file types setting for?  I want to allow images in both file types, but I don't want the user to have to understand the details of why we have those two file types, I just want them to automatically have the right one assigned by field.

Comment: Because you've uploaded a file, the system sees that multiple file types share the mime type, it's asking for clarification. There isn't a way to automatically determine what designation the file falls under. It is my understanding that the field only stores the data in the end, the widget/upload dialog occurs before that.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I'm just not seeing what that field setting is for if not that.

Comment: I've opened an issue about it here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2796131